# How to get a random model with at least N related of multiple `hasmany` models

Tags: mysql, laravel, random, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to combine two features:
- getting a random model
- ... but only if it has at least 1 related model

my URL is `entity/random`
and the below code works well:

```
    if ($entityid == 'random') {
        $random = Entity::all()->random(1);
        return Redirect::to(trans('routes.entities') . '/' . $random->id);
    }
```

Now, my `Entity` model has two relations defined:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comment', 'entity_id');
}

public function sources()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Source', 'entity_id');
}
```

Having them defined, I can get the number of related comments by `$object->comments->count()` or sources by `$object->sources->count()`.
My database is MySQL.

The majority of my `Entities` have NO comments nor sources.

Inspired by  [Laravel Querying Relations Model::has('relation') doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714559/laravel-querying-relations-modelhasrelation-doesnt-work)
i was able to get a random model with at least 2 comments:

```
$random = Entity::has('comments', '>=', DB::raw(2))->get()->random(1);
// produces an Entity with at least 2 comments
```

### TO DO

How to pick a random model only if at least one of two relations count (`sources` OR `comments`) are at least `2`.
Maybe sth like `orHas` exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an [`orHas`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_orHas) method.

You can use it like so:

```
$random = Entity::has('comments', '>=', 2)->orHas('sources', '>=', 2)->get()->random(1);
```

A couple other notes:

The `DB::raw()` syntax is not needed for the `has()` statements. There used to be a bug for sqlite databases that needed this syntax, but that has been resolved since Laravel 4.1.25.

Additionally, you may want to change how you get your random entity. With your current code, you're going to retrieve every record that meets the criteria, and create a full `Entity` object for each one. The more entity records you have, the slower this code is going to get. I would suggest something like this:

```
$id = Entity::has('comments', '>=', 2)->orHas('sources', '>=', 2)->lists('id')->random(1);

$random = Entity::find($id);
```

First, you use the `lists()` method to get all the ids of the entities that match the conditions. As of Laravel 5.2, `lists()` returns a collection. Use the `random()` method on that collection of ids to pick one id to get. Then, `find()` that one id, so only one `Entity` object is created.

Comment: It works. Thank you. 
Strangely enough, all my attempts with no `DB::raw(2)` failed.